# iPhone Dev - How important is Project.pbxproj?

Tags: iphone, xcode, git

What does this file hold and how important is it to keep it "correct"?

I've seen people write [scripts](https://gist.github.com/956761) to just merge any change dealing with it and I've heard [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004135/how-to-merge-conflicts-file-project-pbxproj-in-xcode-use-svn) merging it manually every time.

What is the correct way to handle it and why?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The project.pbxproj contains all of the metadata about your project that Xcode uses to build it;  the settings, the file references, configuration, targeted platforms, etc...

I.e. it is a critically important.

There really isn't a great answer for this.  Typically, teams will avoid conflict by limiting edits to the project to one team member at a time.

The Xcode team has put a lot of effort into making the file merge-friendly.  In managing several large projects via svn, I've generally found that the merges are automatic and painless.

Until they aren't.  And when they aren't, revert, merge changes by hand (i.e. make the changes in the project that conflicted), and move on.

Answer (score 6):

Try my script [xUnique](https://github.com/truebit/xUnique).
What it does:

1. convert `project.pbxproj` to JSON format
2. Iterate all `objects` in JSON and give every UUID an absolute path, and create a new UUID using MD5 hex digest of the path

   - All elements in this json object is actually connected as a tree
   - We give a path attribute to every node of the tree using its unique attribute; this path is the absolute path to the root node,
   - Apply MD5 hex digest to the path for the node
3. Replace all old UUIDs with the MD5 hex digest and also remove unused UUIDs that are not in the current node tree and UUIDs in wrong format
4. Sort the project file inlcuding `children`, `files`, `PBXFileReference` and `PBXBuildFile` list and remove all duplicated entries in these lists

   - see `sort_pbxproj` method in xUnique.py if you want to know the implementation;
   - It's ported from my modified [`sort-Xcode-project-file`](https://github.com/truebit/webkit/commits/master/Tools/Scripts/sort-Xcode-project-file), with some differences in ordering `PBXFileReference` and `PBXBuildFile`
5. With different [options](https://github.com/truebit/xUnique#supported-argument-options), you can use *xUnique* with more flexibility