# should I commit .xcodeproj file in SVN?

Tags: xcode, svn

Should I commit the project file (.xcodeproj)? When I commit this file from one system and update it on a second system, the project gets corrupted and Xcode won't open it.

Is this expected behavior, or am I maybe doing something wrong? Here is my list of ignored files:

> `*.o,*.lo,*.la,*.al,.libs,*.so,*.so.[0-9]*,*.a,*.pyc,*.pyo,*.rej,*~,#*#,.#*,.*.swp,.DS_Store,*.pbxuser,*.perspective,*.perspectivev3,*.project.xcworkspace,*.xcuserdata,*.mode1v3,*.mode2v3,build/,build,/build/`

Should I add something to this list? Should I forget the SVN and switch to GIT?

I am using Cornerstone as SVN client and using Xcode 3.2.5

Please help; I am stuck!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

do commit and track it. specifically, there are a few bits in there which you want - the most important is project.pbxproj. it looks like you have already ignored the user-specific pieces (which is good).

problem is, it will conflict often in distributed environments. break your projects and/or their definitions into smaller pieces to avoid this risk. the project file is a text format - it will merge without issue in some cases.

i do not track these:

```
*.xcbkptlist
*.xcuserstate
```

but you'll want to track *some* of the scheme and workspace files, new in Xc4. again, don't bother tracking the user defined bits, unless you really like them to be tracked, and you are the only person committing.

another thing i recommend is to build to a central location which lies *outside of* your versioned source directories -- no `build/` directories among the sources, even if they are ignored.

Comment: @Justin - Please explain the term "do commit and track it." I am not getting what you mean by "track it". Thanks...

Comment: @Saurabh i meant that you should use svn (git, or another scm system) to record changes to these files.

Comment: ok.. I have one more confusion - if I want to delete a file from xcode how should I delete it. I mean I should delete and send to trash it from xcode? or just delete the reference of file from xcode and delete the file from cornerstone? or delete the reference from xcode and delete the file from finder? Thanks for help

Comment: @Saurabh all of those options would work - just do it the way that works best for you :) if xcode knows it's under version control, then you can ask xcode to delete it from disk and from version control using the same action (select reference+delete+move to trash+remove from scm). you can also delete it from disk (or move it to the trash), then use cornerstone to remove the file from svn, then remove the reference in all xcode projects. or you can delete it in cornerstone, commit, and remove the reference from xcode.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I commit the project file (.xcodeproj) ?

The project file is project.pbxproj, Yes, definitely. project.pbxproj is an important file for Xcode project.

- [iPhone Dev - How important is Project.pbxproj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931788/iphone-dev-how-important-is-project-pbxproj)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Cornorstone this is because the project file itself may have conflicts.
One reason for that was I added a file from first machine and I did not commit and on the second machine also another file was added. The first who commits does not have a problem but when the second commit a conflict will occur.  And also if you changed any attribute in the project configuration. 
A solution is to open the project file that has the conflict with text editor and solve the conflicts.

Comment: Yes !! same as I am facing..  but editing the files with text editor is really a pain.. I am working in a team of 5 programmers..