# Git Restkit submodule .xcodeproj modified all the time

Tags: ios, git, restkit, git-submodules

I am not doing changes to the submodule and it keeps making problems every time I am merging or committing.

Is there a way to ignore that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert with `XCode` projects; But to my understanding this folder holds important files (see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6120152/1031900).

1. But if you know what you're doing, and you'd like to ignore changes to `RestKit.xcodeproj`, do this

   `git update-index --assume-unchanged $(git ls-files RestKit.xcodeproj | tr '\n' ' ')`
   Better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288918/1031900)
2. You could also just add the folder to `.gitignore`, but when commiting don't use `-a` switch. Adding the folder to `.gitignore` file (in the base git folder, if it doesn't exist create it) is done with this line:

   `RestKit.xcodeproj/`
3. If you'd like to completely stop tracking the folder, do this:

   `git rm -r RestKit.xcodeproj`
   Then, add the folder to `.gitignore` file as explained above.

You can probably fine some usefull information in [Git ignore file for Xcode projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49478/1031900)

Hope I helped.