# Which xcode project files should be added to version control

Tags: xcode, version-control, xcode4

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120091/should-i-commit-xcodeproj-file-in-svn) partially addresses my question, but is not comprehensive enough for my XCode 4 needs.

I don't really understand the .xcodeproj structure but it's clear not everything should be in SVN. I previously had only MyProject.xcodeproc/project.pbxproj committed but another developer has committed a whole stack of files - adding xcuserdata and project.xcworkspace subdirs  which both contain a lot of files named _xxx.

For xcode4, is there a well-defined list of which files should actually be considered "the project" and be in a multi-developer source control system, and which are user-specific files which should not be?

Comment: Everything that is not mentioned in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects?rq=1) should be added to version control.

Comment: That does look handy - I didn't find it since I wasn't searching for git! I think this question would be better with that information since it's really VCS-agnostic. Maybe I'll add it myself as an asnwer if nobody else does.