# Is there a good way to rebase and merge the project.pbxproj file using git?

Tags: xcode, git

I have a very annoying issue when rebase the xcodeproj files, is there any way to solve this?

The situation is like this:

(1) A changed the project.pbxproj of demo.xcodeproj, and commit 1;

(2) B changed the project.pbxproj of demo.xcodeproj, and commit 2;

(3)when B rebase the commit 2 to commit 1 , there gonna be lots of conflicts, and it's impossible to merge.

(4) So B have to commit again.

I know the project.pbxproj is an xml file, and the keys in xml are generated randomly.

My question is :

Is there any way to solve this problem? I have no clue about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in fact `demo.xcodeproj` [is a folder](http://bhapca.blogspot.fr/2010/07/how-to-duplicate-project-in-xcode.html), and like every system-dependant configuration file/folder, people tend to avoid versioning them, because they always create conflicts when updating.

Anyway, this question has already been addressed here: [xcodeproj under version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683513/xcodeproj-under-version-control)

Comment: [xcodeproj under version control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683513/xcodeproj-under-version-control) is about how to get a .gitignore. But the project.xcodeproj have to be commited. Could you kindly have a look of my question again?

Comment: I think I expressed myself not correctly, it's about project.pbxproj, not the whole xcodeproj folder.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then this other question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931788/iphone-dev-how-important-is-project-pbxproj


"There really isn't a great answer for this. Typically, teams will avoid conflict by limiting edits to the project to one team member at a time."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe it's really have to handle this problem, we should avoid to edit at a time.