# How to solve xib file's merge conflict?

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, xib, merge-conflict-resolution

Our project use `svn` to manage source version. We have a problem that when a xib is modified by 2 person, it will almost conflict after merging. I've open the confilct file using vim, the information is not readable and I don't know how to solve the merge conflict.

Has anyone met this problem before? How to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the information 'unreadable'? A XIB file is just XML. Have you thought of transitioning to Git? It's automerge tools are far superior to svn.

Comment: Did you try "updating it to the head" and then merging it again?

Answer (score 1):

I would first check if it's possible to manually merge it.
The xib is xml file. You can open it with TextEdit.app and search for "<<<"
You will see two blocks, mine and the revision from svn.

If it's not possible you would revert your code, update and redo the work. And there are a few other ways to resolve it. [How to merge conflicts (file project.pbxproj) in Xcode use svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004135/how-to-merge-conflicts-file-project-pbxproj-in-xcode-use-svn)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that just edit the file with a text editor ...