# Reading GoogleService-Info.plist file gives an error

Tags: ios, firebase, xcode8, xcode-project

I got a merge conflict while merging a branch in app.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file. Conflict was with references related to GoogleService-Info.plist. I followed this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2007358/4863339
to resolve the conflict. Now XCode was showing two same files. Deleting one file would show that entire file has been deleted. I went back to app.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file and deleted the redundant file reference (Costly mistake). Now ,even when I add that GoogleService-Info.plist back XCode gives me following error.

> Copy Plist File error:
>   /Users/user/Documents/app/app/GoogleService-Info.plist:0: error:
>   reading data: The file “GoogleService-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened
>   because there is no such file.

I'm using XCode 8 and info.Plist is pointing to the location where it is supposed to be.

I've tried clean + build even that isn't helping. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by deleting one of the references in app.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file , so there wouldn't be duplicate entries for the same file while merging.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved the issue doing next steps:

Via menu

```
Product -> Clean
```

Or keys combination

```
Shift + Command + K
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the GoogleService-Info.plist from the "Copy Bundle Resources" in your project's Target.