# Unable to resolve project.pbxproj merge conflicts

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I have been unable to perform react-native link due to a conflict in my project.pbxproj file. I have removed the conflicts using this bash script and still has some issues with project.pbxproj file.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=project.pbxproj
sed '/======/d' $FILE | sed '/<<<<</d' | sed '/>>>>>/d' > temp
cat temp > $FILE
rm temp
```

I got this error log by using kin (https://github.com/Karumi/Kin).

```
ERROR: line 257:204 mismatched input 'fileEncoding' expecting {'}', 'xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier'}
ERROR: line 258:146 mismatched input 'fileEncoding' expecting {'}', 'xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier'}
ERROR: line 259:137 mismatched input 'fileEncoding' expecting {'}', 'xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier'}
ERROR: line 260:196 mismatched input 'fileEncoding' expecting {'}', 'xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier'}
ERROR: line 261:143 mismatched input 'fileEncoding' expecting {'}', 'xcLanguageSpecificationIdentifier'}
```

This is my project.pbxproj file(https://gist.github.com/privateOmega/461cdf6dc586e9394aa9a68e94269cb9).

Thanks

PS: my build config is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: have you solved this issue maybe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2007358/3672474 Please follow this if you are encountering the exact problem.